# map function with arguments in Julia

Tags: function, julia, apply

I created the following function in Julia:

```
using StatsBase
function samplesmallGram(A::AbstractMatrix)
    n=size(A,1)
    kpoints=sort(sample((1:n),Int(0.05*n),replace=false))
    Lsmall=A[kpoints,kpoints]
    return kpoints,Lsmall
end
```

I want to apply this function 10 times to a square symmetric matrix `L` I have, through the `map()` command, instead of a `for` loop. I tried

```
map(samplesmallGram(L), 1:1:10)
```

but it doesn't work... How can I achieve this?

Comment: what is `sample(` supposed to do, or what package does it come from?

Comment: This is not how you use `map`. Just look up the doc of `map`, it will tell you the correct syntax.

Comment: Oh sorry! I forgot to mention the package where the command `sample`comes from. Will correct it...

Comment: @DNF I looked at the docs of julialang.org, but they it's not clear and not well explained

Comment: The first input to `map` should be a function. `samplesmallGram` is a function, `samplesmallGram(L)` is not a function, it the output value of a function.

Comment: BTW, it is better to use integer division rather than converting floating point operations to `Int`. Instead of `Int(0.05*n)`, write `div(n, 20)`. It doesn't make any difference to the result, but it's good to be aware of integer division.

Comment: ok, thank you @DNF ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` assumes that its first argument takes elements from the collection you iterate over, so you have to write:

```
map(_ -> samplesmallGram(L), 1:1:10)
```

or

```
map(1:1:10) do _
    samplesmallGram(L)
end
```

By `_` I indicate that I do not intend to use this argument.

However, in such cases I typically prefer to write a comprehension like this:

```
[samplesmallGram(L) for _ in 1:1:10]
```

(as a side note: instead of `1:1:10` you can also write `1:10`)

Comment: Oh, wonderful! I also tried ` map( L -> samplesmallGram(L), 1:1:10)` before and it didn't work as well. So, that's just perfect! A particular reason for writing it as a comprehension? And thank you for the side note ;-)

Comment: And, just in case, if the function has 2 arguments for example? Because I want to do something similar with the `mapslices` command, which i want to apply to each row of A matrix:     `function neig(A::AbstractMatrix,l::Int64) 
    partialsortperm(A,1:l,rev=true) 
end` and after that `mapslices(neig,L,dims=2)`

Comment: then write `map(i -> neig(L, i), 1:10)` (assuming you are still using the same `L` matrix)

Comment: Oh sorry for the misunderstanding... Here, it's a completely different problem. I want to apply the `neig` function to each row of `L` and not repeat it 10 times :-) That's why I used the `mapslices` function but it has 2 arguments: `A`and `l`. I was trying to use the case of one argument you explained to me for coding the case of `mapslices`...

Comment: Then define `neig` to already accept only one row and write `map(neig, eachrow(L))` or broadcast like `neig(eachrow(L))`.

Comment: Ok, il will do it :-) Thank you @Bogumil Kaminski

Comment: Can't do it :-( I need to apply the neig function to each row of L but I have also the argument l of the neigfunction, which I must specify too, i.e. apply the neig function to each row of L for several values of l at each time :-( I will ask a separate question for that.

Answer (score 5):

Typically map is used on each element of a collection, like a conversion process for each element.

https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/index.html#Base.map

```
julia> map(x -> x * 2, [1, 2, 3])
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 4
 6

julia> map(+, [1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30])
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 11
 22
 33
```

Also look at the idea of reducers.  They are related.

You can either pass in L as a global, or use the arrow notation when making the call.

## Arrow Notation

```
output = map(x -> samplesmallGram(L), 1:1:10)
```

Note that x is not the argument to the function in this case, instead
L is passed in 10 times.

## Global

```
A = []
function samplesmallGram(index)
   global A
   n=size(A,1)
   kpoints=sort(sample((1:n),Int(0.05*n),replace=false))
   Lsmall=A[kpoints,kpoints]
   return kpoints,Lsmall
end

output = map(samplesmallGram, 1:1:10)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Your explanation is clearer than the one of julialang page ;-)

Comment: Concerning the Arrow notation, it's funny because I was mentionning to your colleague that I used `map(L -> samplesmallGram(L), 1:1:10)` with no success, so yes, I just had to change the `L` argument of `map`!